# How do I get a div container to resize it's height so that the bottom of the container always splits a block of text (example below)

Tags: html, css, responsive

I was wondering how I could get the blue-ish div to resize so that the bottom always splits the "HEADER" in half.

Right now, I have the text as a fixed position and its position adjusts to the bottom of the viewport. The blue div is fixed to the top and I have its height adjusting to the viewport. I have included a code snippet of my CSS.

```css
/* text styles */

h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10vw;
    color: #C7DCEA;
    letter-spacing: 1.44px;
    line-height: 6vw;
}

p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #C7DCEA;
    line-height: 1.5vw;
}

/* div styles */

body{
    background-color: #070707;
}

div.header {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6vw;
    left:1.8vw;
    z-index: 2;
}

div.paragraph{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5vw;
    left:3vw;
    z-index:3;
}

div.box{
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color:#2248C4; /* purple */
    width:100vw;
    height:38vw;
    z-index: 1;
}


    <!-- HTML --!>
    <div class="box">
    </div>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>QWOTE</h1>
    </div>

   <div class="paragraph">
        <p>Every day on this site (or at least, hopefully every day) I plan on sharing some cool things other people say. <br> I'll say some things about what they say, and maybe you'll find it helpful (or not, up to you).
        </p>    
   </div>
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML

Comment: Look at this [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/w4qb2o6t/9/), Is this you want

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below snippet will solve your problem.

Let me know if you want to anything else.

Waiting for your feedback :-)

```css
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90px;
    color: #C7DCEA;
    letter-spacing: 1.44px;
}

p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #C7DCEA;
}

/* div styles */

body{
    background-color: #070707;
}

div.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 72vh;
    left:1.8vw;
  margin-top:-113px;
    z-index: 2;
}

div.paragraph{
    position: fixed;
    top: 72vh;
    left: 3vw;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

div.box{
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color:#2248C4; /* purple */
    width:100vw;
    height:72vh;
    z-index: 1;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  h1 {font-size:50px;}
  div.header{margin-top:-64px}
  div.paragraph{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
    </div>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>QWOTE</h1>
    </div>

   <div class="paragraph">
        <p>Every day on this site (or at least, hopefully every day) I plan on sharing some cool things other people say. <br> I'll say some things about what they say, and maybe you'll find it helpful (or not, up to you).
        </p>    
   </div>
```